# How do I prevent an oxy plot graph from zooming on one axis?

Tags: c#, .net, oxyplot

Graph at start:

[image]

Graph after zooming a bit:

[image]

**Question:** How do I keep the full vertical data of the graph visible without having to pan up and down to try and see it?

I imagine the graph would need to stretch out horizontally to do this. I have tried setting min/max ranges to achieve this, but they don't seem to have the desired result. I cannot find any settings in the documentation to disable just one zoom axis.

Answer (score 6):

In the graph plot model, add the desired axis and disable the axis zoom:

```
var pm = new PlotModel { Title = "My Plot" };

//Define the x axis
DateTimeAxis xAxis = new DateTimeAxis();            
xAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;

//Define the y axis
LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
yAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
//Disable the axis zoom
yAxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;

//Add the Axes to the graph
pm.Axes.Add(xAxis);
pm.Axes.Add(yAxis);
```

Also, if you don't want to disable the zoom, if you scroll the mouse wheel with he cursor at one axis, the zoom will be applied only to that axis.